# LEDGEE NANO S WITH BOTH BTC WALLET AND MONERO WALLET

Tags: ledger

I have created on my Ledger nano S vers.1.5.5. a BTC wallet. I have written my 24 words and Ledger Desktop vers.1.8.1. works perfectly.
After this I have installed on Ledger nano S the MONERO APP vers.1.2.2 and on my PC MONERO GUI v.0.14.0.2. I have downloaded all blockchain and I have created an hardware wallet.
I show in MONERO GUI my XMR balance.
But I have 3 questions:
- The 24 seed words created when I created BTC wallet are usable only for BTC Wallet? If I enter in MONERO GUI- setting - seed and keys I only view Public view Key and Public Spend Key. All other field secret view key - secret spend key and Mnemonic seed are empty. So if I should lost my ledger and I don't have my 25 seed words to restore my wallet and my money.
This matter worries me.
- When I login into Ledger Monero APP the ledger dispaly shows an address like an address wallet or a spend key. What is the function of this data, which has never changed since installation of MONERO APP ?? What is it for?
- finally, why in LEDGER LIVE DESkTOP i see only BTC balance? Is it not possible to show also XMR balance?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my English.

Giovanni

Comment: PLEASE, MAY EVERYBODY HELP ME?

Comment: Please see my comment to your duplicate question. Also, there is no need for SHOUTING.

Comment: sorry it was not my intention.....

Comment: Please delete all your duplicate questions then and edit out the SHOUTING on any that remain. Thanks.